# GRANT/REVOKE execute privileges for an user oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-grant, sql-revoke

How exactly is the GRANT/REVOKE privileges affecting the database.

I have a solution ready for a problem where one of my components(an executable) is not identifying my oracle config packages. But is it possible for me to test by revoking with this,

```
revoke execute on package_name to user1;
```

And then again grant,

```
grant execute on package_name to user1;
```

In short, can this in anyway affect the privileges negatively. This is mainly because user1 is a generic user so that's why I am being cautious.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “affecting the database“?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But of course that revoking a privilege affects that user *negatively* ... it won't be able to use that package any more.

Things can be even more complicated if that user (`user1`) has granted privilege to other users (as it was granted privilege `with grant option`) because - once you revoke privileges from `user1`, Oracle will automatically revoke privileges from all those users/roles (that's what we'd call a *cascading effect*).

Therefore, be careful. I guess that your best option to test it is to have a separate - testing - database. There you can do anything you want, as it won't affect nobody in production.

Finally, it is `revoke privilege FROM user`, not `TO` (referring to the 1st statement you posted).